# How to sort a list in lisp?

Tags: list, sorting, lisp, autocad, autolisp

I have a list in lisp like this:

```
(
    ((5 6) (2 7)) 
    ((5 4) (2 9)) 
    ((1 8) (7 7))
)
```

I want to sort it by all these conditions:

1. Just by first elemens: `(5 6)`, `(5 4)`, `(1 8)`
2. In these elements, first sort by x and then by y: `(1 8)` `(5 4)` `(5 6)`

At the end I want to have a list that sorted by above conditions in first elements and each one of these elements has their second element:

```
(
    ((1 8) (7 7)) 
    ((5 4) (2 9))
    ((5 6) (2 7)) 
)
```

Can you give me a subroutine to do that, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show *any* evidence of even trying to solve this yourself?

Comment: What variant of LISP are you using? Common LISP, AutoLISP?

Comment: @Lee Mac I'm using Visual Lisp

Answer (score 4):

Since you state in the comments that you're using Visual LISP, you can use the standard [`vl-sort`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-F3B27BD2-27FA-4185-B22C-85509175C171-htm.html) function (which implements the Quicksort algorithm) in the following way:

```lisp
(setq l
  '(
       ((5 6) (2 7)) 
       ((5 4) (2 9)) 
       ((1 8) (7 7))
    )
)
```

```lisp
(vl-sort l
   '(lambda ( a b )
        (if (= (caar  a) (caar  b))
            (< (cadar a) (cadar b))
            (< (caar  a) (caar  b))
        )
    )
)
```

Here, `if` statement within the lambda comparison function tests whether the first elements of the first sublist for each item (the *"x-coordinates"*) are equal, and if so, compares the second element (the *"y-coordinates"*).

For a given pair of items within the `lambda` function:

```
a = ((5 6) (2 7))

(car a)   = (5 6)
(caar a)  = 5
(cadar a) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve it:

```
(defun Sort ()
  (setq li nil)
  (setq liso nil)
  (setq newptlist nil)
  (defun AS:Sort (lst / newptlist)
    (setq xvals (list))
    (foreach pt lst
      (if (not (vl-remove-if-not
         '(lambda (x) (equal (car (car pt)) x 0.0001))
         xvals
           )
      )
    (setq xvals (cons (car (car pt)) xvals))
      )
    )
    (setq xvals (vl-sort xvals '(lambda (x1 x2) (< x1 x2))))
    (foreach xval xvals
      (setq pts       (vl-remove-if-not
            '(lambda (x) (equal xval (car (car x)) 0.0001))
            lst
              )
        pts       (vl-sort
            pts
            '(lambda (pt1 pt2) (< (cadr (car pt1)) (cadr (car pt2))))
              )
        newptlist (append newptlist pts)
      )
    )
  )
  (setq li (list (list '(5 6) '(2 7))
         (list '(5 4) '(2 9))
         (list '(1 8) '(7 7))
       )
  )
  (setq liso (AS:Sort li1))
;;;  PRINT
  (print "li= ")
  (print li)
  (print "liso= ")
  (print liso)
  (princ)
)
```

Comment: This seems to be a far more convoluted way of using `vl-sort` than that which I proposed in my answer to achieve the same result - I'm curious as to why you would opt for this method?

Answer (score 0):

I could not resist answering this, because I was trying to think if there is a sort algorithm which was very easy to write in Lisp while being suitably terrible, and I arrived at this (see the comments: the algorithm must be well-known but I don't know what it's name is).

Note that there is quite a lot of intentional wheel-reinvention here: the code is not intentionally *opaque* but it is meant to be intentionally hard to submit as a homework answer.

It's in Racket which may not be what you meant by 'lisp'.

```
#lang racket

(define (remove/one e l #:test (equivalent? eqv?))
  ;; remove the first occurence of e from l using equivalent?
  ;; as the equivalence predicate.
  (let loop ([lt l] [a '()])
    (cond
      [(null? lt)
       l]
      [(equivalent? e (first lt))
       (append (reverse a) (rest lt))]
      [else
       (loop (rest lt) (cons (first lt) a))])))

(define (extremum l <?)
  ;; find the extremum of l under <?
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (let loop ([lt (rest l)] [candidate (first l)])
        (cond
          [(null? lt)
           candidate]
          [(<? (first lt) candidate)
           (loop (rest lt) (first lt))]
          [else
           (loop (rest lt) candidate)]))))

(define (terrible-sort l less-than?
                       #:key (key identity))
  ;; A terrible sort function.  This works by repeatedly finding the extremum
  ;; of l & then recursing on l with the extremum removed.
  ;; less-than? is assumed to provide a partial order on the elements of l:
  ;; equivalence is defined by less-than?.  key is a key extractor in the
  ;; usual way: there is no Schwartzian transform though.
  ;;
  ;; I haven't stopped to think about the complexity of this but it's at least
  ;; quadratic (and I think it probably is quadratic?).  It's also very consy.
  ;;
  ;; This algorithm must have a name.
  ;;
  (define (>? a b)
    (less-than? (key b) (key a)))
  (define (=? a b)
    (let ([av (key a)]
          [bv (key b)])
      (and (not (less-than? av bv))
           (not (less-than? bv av)))))
  (let loop ([lt l] [sorted '()])
    (if (null? lt)
        sorted
        (let ([smallest (extremum lt >?)])
          (loop (remove/one smallest lt #:test =?)
                (cons smallest sorted))))))

(define (answer l)
  (terrible-sort l (λ (a b)
                     ;; compare two lists of numbers
                     (let loop ([at a] [bt b])
                       (if (null? at)
                           (if (null? bt)
                               #f
                               (error "unequal lengths"))
                           (match-let ([(cons ath att) at]
                                       [(cons bth btt) bt])
                             (cond
                               [(< ath bth) #t]
                               [(> ath bth) #f]
                               [else (loop att btt)])))))
                 #:key first))

(define data '(((5 6) (2 7)) 
               ((5 4) (2 9)) 
               ((1 8) (7 7))))
```

Comment: Thank you Lee, But I'm using Visual Lisp. I don't know how can I use it in Vlisp, or is it possible to use it in Vlisp.

Comment: [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp: `[sort '(((5 6) (2 7)) ((5 4) (2 9)) ((1 8) (7 7))) : car] -> 
(((1 8) (7 7)) ((5 4) (2 9)) ((5 6) (2 7)))`.  Default value of the second argument, selected by the `:` symbol, is the`less` function. `less` walks lists and compares them lexicographically, so ...